# Outlook not displaying background image inside table row

Tags: html, outlook

I'm a simple amateur in html coding and i'm facing problems with outlook not displaying a background image inside a table row.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://
www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>TEST #3</title>
</head>

<body link="#FFF" vlink="#b3c010" alink="#b3c010">
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#000000;">Não consegue visualizar este email correctamente? <a href="http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/minuto_consulai.html" style="color:#999999;">Veja aqui a versão online</a></p></td></tr>
</table>
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #b3c010; background-image:url(http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/imagens/background.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y;" align="center">
  <tbody>

  <tr><td width="650" height="452"><img src="http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/imagens/img1.jpg" width="650" height="452" alt="Minuto Consulai"></td></tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr style="background:url(http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/imagens/background.jpg) background-repeat:repeat-y;">
  <td>
  <table width="518" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>  
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03/imagens/foto.jpg" width="518" height="264" alt="Proder Programa de Desenvolvimento Rural"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="451" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>
        <p style=" font-family:&#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#b3c010; text-align:justify;">18-22 E 25-29 DE SETEMBRO DE 2012 > PÓS-LABORAL</p>
          <p style=" font-family:&#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#54575A; text-align:justify;">A CONSULAI organiza, em parceria com a APAS Floresta e a Syngenta, o <span style="font-weight: bold;"><a href="http://www.consulai.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color: #54575A;">Curso de Aplicação de Produtos Fitofarmacêuticos em Explorações Florestais</a></span>, homologado pela Direção Regional de Agricultura, o qual permitirá a obtenção do Cartão de Aplicador.</p>
      <p style=" font-family:&#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#54575A; text-align:justify;">O curso decorrerá em regime pós-laboral, terá uma duração de 35 horas e terá início no dia <span style="font-weight: bold;">04 de setembro de 2012</span>. A  formação será ministrada nas instalações da APAS FLORESTA e em propriedades florestais, no Cadaval.</p>
      <p style=" font-family:&#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; font-weight: bold; color:#54575A; text-align:justify;"><a href="http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03/pdf/FOLHETO_CURSO_APLICADORES_SET 2012.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color: #54575A;">Ficha de inscrição</a></p>
      <p style=" font-family:&#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#54575A; text-align:justify;">Contactos:<br />Sónia Gonçalves (CONSULAI)<br /><span style="font-weight: bold;">TLM</span> 918 928 923&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">T</span> 213 629 553&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">F</span> 213 621 091<br /><span style="font-weight: bold;">E</span> <a href="mailto:sgoncalves@consulai.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color: #54575A;">sgoncalves@consulai.com</a></p>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td width="518" height="82"><img src="http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03/imagens/certificacoes.jpg" width="518" height="82" alt="Certificações"></td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
<!-- END conteudos -->

<tr><td width="650" height="108"><img src="http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/imagens/footer.jpg" width="650" height="108" alt="Contactos Consulai"></td></tr>
</table>
<!-- END main content -->

<!-- START top bar -->
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"><p style=" font-family:&#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#54575A; text-align:justify;">PARA DEIXAR DE RECEBER O MINUTO CONSULAI ENVIE-NOS <a href="mailto:consulai@consulai.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color: #54575A;">UM E-MAIL</a> COM O ASSUNTO REMOVER.</p></td></tr>
</table>
<!-- END top bar -->
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

<tbody><tr>

        </tr>
</tbody></table></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays fine in other email clients and i'm using mailchimp to send it out. The problematic row is this:

```
<tr style="background:url(http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/imagens/background.jpg) background-repeat:repeat-y;">
```

I've also tried the VML hack but i can't seem to get it work with this row.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 4):

According to http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth Outlook 2007 - 2010 only support background images for the body tag.

You either can use

```
<body style="background:url(http://www.consulai.com/minuto_consulai/03_alterado/imagens/background.jpg) background-repeat:repeat-y;"…>
```

or embed the images in question as img tags.